# Android ViewHolder yes or not?

Tags: android

I'm still trying to find ways for getting better performance in my listview. One of the things I saw on Google I/O 2009 video was the performance of using ViewHolder.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA

As you can see at minute 12:00 the difference of performance of using a viewHolder is huge for others. I was doing the "dumb" way, which means not implementing the viewHolder feature.

So, I gave a try.

Without the viewHolder, I load in my listview 20 items (which contains a small Image, title, description and price (ImageView, TextView, TextView, TextView)) in exactly 3 seconds.

I implemented successfully the method viewHolder with the same objects and...I got exactly 3 seconds also when loading the 20 items in the listview.

I was expecting to reduce this time to at least half.

What do you guys think? Is it normal?

Comment: test with more than 100 items and check if you see any difference.

Comment: 3 seconds for 20 items sounds like you're spending most of your time doing something else than `findViewById()` and the benefit of the view holder pattern for such a small dataset does not show up in measurements.

Comment: How you are populating the listview , are you using Async Task?

Comment: It doesnt matter if its 100 or 1000 or 5000 items, view holder pattern speeds up scrolling not initial loading

Comment: Well, if viewHolder only speeds up scrolling, then I didn't see any improve comparing to my old code.
With 20 items it does a small break when reaching the top of listview or the bottom of listview.
It also breaks if I scroll fast.

Comment: @laalto and !Shashank, I do believe my problem is on the images. They are converted from bytes[] to bitmap, and it can be images with the extension PNG, which are way larger.

Answer (score 2):

The ViewHolder doesnt improve loading speed on first load, it improves the scrolling speed. Even with ViewHolder you have to use the findViewById method on some occasions. As it only improves performance if you are reusing a view and just editing its contents. 
images/texts and stuff.

Yes it is normal that it doesnt speed up your inflation/loadSpeed. To improve loading you will have to use different techniques :)

How do you provide the Data for your Views? are you doing some sort of "heavy work" on your UIThread while scrolling?

Comment: i think this should answer your question :)